# Статическое поле в generics/template

Tags: java, c#, c++, generics

Есть Java generics класс типа:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   static long myField=System.currentTimeMillis();

   //blah-blah
}
```

Создаются два объекта:

```
MyClass<String> var1=new MyClass<String>();
MyClass<Integer> var2=new MyClass<Integer>();
```

вопрос: одинаковы ли `var1.myField` и `var2.myField`?

**Update**

А если это будет шаблон в С++/C# - тогда будут они одинаковы или нет?

Comment: Да, одинаковые, т.к. информация о типе в параметре "стирается", и обе переменные во время выполнения относятся к одному типу. Для примитивов это может быть будет как-то иначе работать (но вряд ли), но до генериков с примитивами нам еще долго.

Comment: Отвечу за С++ : 1) не факт,что значение в милисекундах будет одинаковое - может и тикнуть как раз таки. 2) поскольку присвоение по значению в POD тип - то это будет 2 разные переменные в разных адрессах. 3) Чтобы они были одинаковые - можно присвоить каждому в качестве поля указателя/ссылки на объект singleton умеющий возвращать время (вариант с интерфейсным указателем на объект реализовующий данный механизм тоже подойдет). Так как время в программе это дело константа для всех - я бы выбрал singleton с статическими методами работы с временем.

Comment: В C# это, вроде как, тоже дженериками называется, а не шаблонами.

Comment: Это разве так важно? Я и в Java дженерики называю шаблонами (да и не только я)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Java с type erasure `MyClass<T1>` и `MyClass<T2>` — это по сути в рантайме один и тот же класс. У C# нет type erasure, поэтому `MyClass<T1>` и `MyClass<T2>` — разные классы. Отсюда следует и различие в статических полях: если класс один и тот же, статическое поле общее.

У C++ template — это вообще текстовая подстановка по сути, каждый шаблон класса инстанциируется в отдельный класс, соответственно и статические переменные там разделены.

Answer (score 12):

Ответ: Да, они одинаковые для Java

Ваш пример не самый хороший для демонстрации этого. Известно, что `StringBuilder` не ссылается в один pool и каждый раз создаёт новый объект. Будем использовать его для подтверждения утверждения:

```
public class Clazz<T> {
    static StringBuilder myField= new StringBuilder("Test text");

    public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Clazz<String> var1=new Clazz<String>();
        Clazz<Integer> var2=new Clazz<Integer>();
        // Одинаковые ли ссылки на объект?
        System.out.println(var1.myField == var2.myField); 
        // Одинаковы ли содержания объектов?
        System.out.println(var1.myField.toString().equals(var2.myField.toString())); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

---

В C++, на сколько я понял, нет прямого аналога generic class. Там есть шаблоны и работают они как-то по-другому. Я набросал немного кода:

```
template <class T> class Test {
    public: static int count;
};

template <class T> int Test <T> ::count;

int main() {
    Test <int> a;
    Test <int> b;
    Test <double> c;
    a.count = 2;
    b.count = 1;
    c.count = 1;
    // Одинаковы ли ссылки?
    cout << (&a.count == &b.count) << endl;
    // Одинаковы ли содержания?
    cout << (a.count == b.count)<< endl;
    // Одинаковы ли ссылки?
    cout << (&a.count == &c.count) << endl;
    // Одинаковы ли содержания?
    cout << (a.count == c.count) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Статическая переменная внутри шаблона оказывается одинаковой для объектов, созданных одинаковым типом (`int`) и разная для разных типов. Вывод этой программы следующий:

Output:

```
1
1
0
1
```

---

В C# провести исследование нет возможности (ОС не поддерживает), но я нашёл похожий вопрос на англоязычном StackOverflow: [Are static members of a generic class tied to the specific instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037203/are-static-members-of-a-generic-class-tied-to-the-specific-instance).

Дела там, похоже, не особо отличаются от C++.

> Статическая переменная одинакова для всех экземпляров одинакового типа.
>   `Foo<int>` и `Foo<string>` - два разных типа. Это можно показать в следующем примере:
>
> ```
> // Результатом будет "False" 
> Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo<int>) == typeof(Foo<string>));
> ```
>
> Это можно найти в 1.6.5 параграфе спецификации языка C# (for
>   C# 3):
>
> ....

Comment: Не сказал бы что ваш пример лучше. И да, у StringBuilder equals не реализован, он просто сравнивает ссылки на объекты.

Comment: @Russtam, спасибо за `equals`. Добавил преобразование в `String`. В примере ТС примитивный тип. Там ссылки не сравнишь. А в этом примере можно сравнить ссылки.

Comment: Можно еще присвоить полю значение и убедиться, что оно одинаково для обоих вариантов.

Comment: @zRrr, не знаю, правильно ли я вас понял, но значение присваивается `myField`. Там создаётся объект с вызовом конструктора с параметром `String`.

Comment: ну вдруг, если сделать `var1.myField = new StringBuilder("");` значения перестанут совпадать (на самом деле нет) :).

Comment: @zRrr, да, конечно, так тоже можно было сделать.

Answer (score 7):

C#: нет, они разные

```
class Generic<T>
{
    static object obj = new object();

    public object GetObject()
    {
        return obj;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var g1 = new Generic<string>();
    var g2 = new Generic<bool>();

    Console.WriteLine(
        (g1.GetObject() == g2.GetObject()
        ? string.Empty
        : "Not ") + "Same");
}
```

Output:

```
Not Same
```

Answer (score 7):

Для C++ разные, т.к. разные типы аргумента для шаблона порождают разные классы, никак не связанные друг с другом.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct MyClass {
   static long myField;
};

int main() {
    auto var1 = MyClass<int>();
    auto var2 = MyClass<char>();

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (&var1.myField == &var2.myField) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
false
```